# django - handling reference model in admin app

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these 2 models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class MappingRule(models.Model):
    rule_type = models.IntegerField()
    mapping_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
```

I am using django's admin app and I want to customize it - I want to be able to add a MappingRule to an existing Profile. Currently I can add a MappingRule and on that page I select from a dropdown the profile, but I want to be able to be in the context of a profile and there to create a rule for it - i.e. I don't have a dropdown of profiles to select since I am in a context of a specific profile. Is this possible?

I know there's the inline model option but this is not good for my case because MappingRule needs an add page of its own since it has more data then what I wrote and more reference fields / other models that refernce it

********************** *EDIT* ******************:

just to clarify - a user in the system first creates a profile. Then, he can add rules to that profile. There's no sense to have a page listing all rules in the system - I want to be able to be in the profile list page / profile change page, and there have links to:

1. view all rules of that profile
2. add a new rule to the profile

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You want an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question - this solution is not suitable for me